# In what order are the vertexes specified for the polygon in Vulkan?

Tags: vulkan

I know that for OpenGL, by default, the vertices are set in a counterclockwise direction. Is this the case in Vulkan?

For OpenGL:

```
A
|\
| \
|  \
B---C
```

Comment: Broadly speaking, Vulkan is not an API with defaults. You usually have to specify everything you do in the API.

Answer (score 0):

In Vulkan you need everything explicitly specified, and you can choose between counter-clockwise or clockwise when you set your `VkPipelineRasterizationStateCreateInfo` (see [VkFrontFace](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2-extensions/html/vkspec.html#primsrast-polygons-basic)).

```
VkPipelineRasterizationStateCreateInfo rastStateInfo{};
rastStateInfo.frontFace = VK_FRONT_FACE_COUNTER_CLOCKWISE;
```

Comment: It isn't by default *anything*. In Vulkan you are *required* to specify what the front face will be. That struct, and its members, are not optional, so you always have to specify it.

Comment: if we don't specify a value for `frontface`, the value is still set to zero which corresponds to `VK_FRONT_FACE_COUNTER_CLOCKWISE`, but this is not recommended, no?

Comment: "*the value is still set to zero*" Only if you zero-initialize the structure. If you just default-initialize it (ie `VkPipelineRasterizationStateCreateInfo rastStateInfo;`), then it will have an undefined value.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @florianvazelle 's answer, it's worth noting that a flag value of 0 does not necessarily mean the "default" in a broader sense.

For example, `VK_PRESENT_MODE_FIFO_KHR` is guaranteed to be present in Vulkan, and can be considered as "default" in a broader sense, but its integer value is 2 instead of 0.